# I have an API, and I don't know how to get the data

Tags: c#, api

There is an API for fake details about people:
https://uinames.com/api/?amount=25&ext

the problem is that I don't know how to get the data.

I tried to download the data using HttpClient and the data move to a class

```
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"https://uinames.com/api/?amount={amount}&ext");
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UINames>(responseBody);

  public class UIName
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        //etc
    }

  public class UINames : List<UIName>
    {

    }
```

I want the data on each person (name, last name, phone)

Comment: Are you getting an error or do you simply not get the correct values? Also what is your `UINames` class? Please show the code of that class (`UINames`).

Comment: You don't need to create an empty class `UINames`. Just use `UIName[]` or `List<UIName>`. You can use a [`foreach` loop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) to loop over every element in the array/list and look at the data there. It seems like the problem is that you don't know how to _process_ the data rather than _getting_ the data. We can't really help you with that since it's really dependent on your situation etc. Do you not know about `foreach` and other ways of processing a collection of items? That is basic programming knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The api returns an array, and therefore you should use

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UIName[]>(responseBody);
```

or

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UIName>>(responseBody);
```

Comment: I don't really understand this... and I don't know what to do

Comment: @CodeLikeAl3oSS What do you mean you don't know what to do? Simply replace `UINames` with `UINames[]` in `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. If this doesn't work you need to show us your `UINames` class (actually you should do that either way -> edit the question and add that class).

Comment: @CodeLikeAl3oSS try `UIName[]`. are you getting any errors?

Comment: No I don't get any errors but how can I get the data now?

Comment: The data should be stored in the variable `model` you can access it like an array: `model[0].Name` or in a loop: `foreach(UIName name in model)` etc..